# What type of terminal to support if implementing a terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

I have heard that VT100 is the de facto standard. Does it mean if I can just support VT100 and then my terminal can work for existing commandline applications without big problems? If not, how to make sure that terminal is practical? Is there any reference that can help to reach this goal?

Comment: Tell us more about what you're trying to do.  Are you writing it as a learning exercise?  To do something that none of the available terminal emulators do?  To be used in some non-standard environment?

Comment: Why implement a new terminal emulator. Join one of the existing open source emulator development efforts instead if you want to do something useful.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Yeah, for learning exercise. I'm also thinking how to implement a shell in it. Suggestions are helpful to let me avoid implementing something not practical.

Comment: To me the question is quite legit. The motivation is clear, if you want to create a terminal emulator from scratch you just want it to be useful, modern, supporting most of software people will run inside of it. It is not really fair to mark it as "opinion based" although maybe the question could be rephrased to something like "how to write a terminal emulator from scratch to be compatible with most of the terminal-based software in use".

Answer (score 13):

You're about to get Thomas Dickey overheated.

Ignore the samizdat that has been circulating for years about VT10x terminals.  Much of it is wrong.  The DEC VT100, VT101, and VT102 implemented a very specific set of functions, which one can learn from reading their doco.

That is *not* what people who go incorrectly bandying around the terms `vt100` and `vt102` actually mean, however.  Often, what they are talking about is a terminal emulation that does a whole lot *more* than what a real VT10x did, as well as a whole lot *less*.  A real DEC VT102 had an attached serial printer, and control sequences for accessing it, for example.  It furthermore did *not* have many of the control sequences from later terminal emulators and real terminals that people erroneously ascribe to "vt102".  It had no concept of SGR colour changes, for example.

You have two basic choices:

- Implement something that is compatible with an existing terminal type that is defined in the termcap/terminfo databases.  If you do this, you must do it correctly, exactly copying all of the existing terminal type's described behaviour.  (The nosh toolset's terminal emulator does this, emulating on Linux the `linux` terminal type.  It has to copy the `linux` terminal type's quirky and limited extended key and function key encodings.)
- Implement your own terminal type, whose behaviour is designed by you, which you then have to get included in the termcap/terminfo database.  The PuTTY terminal emulator, strictly speaking, does this.  The correct terminfo description for it is  [`putty`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty), [`putty-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-256color), or [`putty-sco`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-sco).

For the former, what is standard is irrelevant, as you have to copy the described behaviour no matter how non-standard it may be.  For the latter, do not look for de facto standards.  Look at the *actual* standards, some of which have been around since 1976.

- ECMA-48 (first published in 1976 and later adopted as an ISO/IEC standard, ISO/IEC 6429) describes:

  - C0 control codes,
  - C1 control codes (which are little known but deal in several useful things like setting/clearing tabstops and forward/reverse index)
  - 7-bit aliases for all C1 control codes (for example, ESC `[` is a 7-bit alias for the *actual* 8-bit control character U+009B),
  - control sequences introduced by CSI (for which there is a general syntax in the standard that many samizdat-written control sequence parsers get wrong),
  - and a whole lot of other stuff.
- ISO/IEC 2022 describes switching amongst 7-bit character sets.  If you are going to implement UTF-8 capability from the start, ISO/IEC 2022 is best completely ignored, as Markus Kuhn and the inventors of `mosh` will tell you.
- ISO/IEC 8613-6 (published in 1989 and revised in 1994) describes extensions to ECMA-48 for colour SGR control sequences, both "indexed colour" selection from a palette and "direct colour" RGB.  (Both *direct colour* and *indexed colour* are defined in ISO/IEC 8613-2.  You'll probably know the latter by the samizdat name of "256 colour".)

  **Important note:**  Almost all implementations implement this standard wrongly, because they worked from samizdat (or simply copied one another) rather than from the actual standard.  The standard says in §13.1.8 to use colon (`:`, "3/10") as a sub-parameter separator; almost all implementations erroneously use semi-colon (`;`), introducing a parsing ambiguity.  A lot of softwares have accommodated this error.

### Further reading

- *[Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)*.  ECMA-48.  5th edition. 1991. ECMA International.
- *[Information technology — Open Document Architecture (ODA) and interchange format: Document structures](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.412/en)*.  T.412.  International Telecommunication Union.
- *[Information technology — Open Document Architecture (ODA) and interchange format: Character content architectures](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.416/en)*.  T.416.  International Telecommunication Union.
- *[Information technology— Open Document Architecture (ODA) and Interchange Format: Character content architectures](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=22943)*.  ISO/IEC 8613-6:1994.  International Organization for Standardization.
- Markus Kuhn (2009).  "[What are the issues related to UTF-8 terminal emulators?](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#term)".  *UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux*.
- Keith Winstein, Anders Kaseorg, et al. (2012). "[ISO 2022 locking escapes](https://mosh.mit.edu/#techinfo)".  *mosh technical info*.
- *[VT420 Programmer Reference Manual](http://vaxhaven.com/images/5/55/EK-VT420-RM-002.pdf)*.  EK-VT420-RM-002.  February 1992.  Digital.
- *[VT520/VT525 Video Terminal Programmer Information](http://vaxhaven.com/images/b/b5/EK-VT520-RM-A01.pdf)*.  EK-VT520-RM.  July 1994.  Digital.
- Thomas E. Dickey (1997). "[What is a VT220?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#what_is_vt220)". *xterm Frequently Asked Questions*.  invisible-island.

Comment: So detailed! Before I decide whether to edit the question, I want to know how to make sure most commandline applications can run well in the terminal?

Comment: Especially, how can a custom terminal type like putty's work for the existing programs?

Comment: Most command-line applications that need advanced TTY control won't implement it on their own, but use a library to handle the actual control codes. Historically, this library was known by the name `curses`; the modern version is `ncurses`. These libraries use a `terminal description` that identifies all the features available in a particular terminal type. The terminal description comes either from the `terminfo` database (modern) or from the `/etc/termcap` file (classic). So if you implement a new terminal type, you should also write a description for it and install it to your system(s).

Comment: ...and before anyone else comments on this: yes, the `termcap` vs. `terminfo` is actually yet another difference between the legacies of BSD vs. SystemV.