# making bind -p human readable

Tags: bash, ubuntu

The [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/bind.html) for bind appears not to link to a syntax explanation, so while attempting to convert `bind -p` into human readable format I can filter out the garbage from 483 down to 109, but then am only able to understand 73;

```
bind -p 2>/dev/null \
| grep -vP "digit-argument|do-lowercase-version|not bound|self-insert" \
| perl -pe 's/\\e/[alt]/g;s/\\C/[control]/g' \
| grep -P "[\-\]].\""

"[control]-g": abort
"[control]-x[control]-g": abort
"[alt][control]-g": abort
"[control]-j": accept-line
"[control]-m": accept-line
"[control]-b": backward-char
"[control]-h": backward-delete-char
"[control]-?": backward-delete-char
"[control]-x[control]-?": backward-kill-line
"[alt][control]-h": backward-kill-word
"[alt][control]-?": backward-kill-word
"[alt]b": backward-word
"[alt]<": beginning-of-history
"[control]-a": beginning-of-line
"[alt]c": capitalize-word
"[control]-]": character-search
"[alt][control]-]": character-search-backward
"[control]-l": clear-screen
"[control]-i": complete
"[alt]!": complete-command
"[alt]/": complete-filename
"[alt]@": complete-hostname
"[alt]{": complete-into-braces
"[alt]~": complete-username
"[alt]$": complete-variable
"[control]-d": delete-char
"[control]-x[control]-v": display-shell-version
"[alt]l": downcase-word
"[alt][control]-i": dynamic-complete-history
"[control]-x[control]-e": edit-and-execute-command
"[alt]>": end-of-history
"[control]-e": end-of-line
"[control]-x[control]-x": exchange-point-and-mark
"[control]-f": forward-char
"[control]-s": forward-search-history
"[alt]f": forward-word
"[alt]g": glob-complete-word
"[alt]^": history-expand-line
"[alt]#": insert-comment
"[alt]*": insert-completions
"[alt].": insert-last-argument
"[alt]_": insert-last-argument
"[control]-k": kill-line
"[alt]d": kill-word
"[control]-n": next-history
"[alt]n": non-incremental-forward-search-history
"[alt]p": non-incremental-reverse-search-history
"[control]-o": operate-and-get-next
"[alt]=": possible-completions
"[alt]?": possible-completions
"[control]-p": previous-history
"[control]-q": quoted-insert
"[control]-v": quoted-insert
"[control]-x[control]-r": re-read-init-file
"[control]-r": reverse-search-history
"[alt][control]-r": revert-line
"[alt]r": revert-line
"[control]-@": set-mark
"[alt] ": set-mark
"[alt][control]-e": shell-expand-line
"[alt]&": tilde-expand
"[control]-t": transpose-chars
"[alt]t": transpose-words
"[control]-x[control]-u": undo
"[control]-_": undo
"[control]-u": unix-line-discard
"[control]-w": unix-word-rubout
"[alt]u": upcase-word
"[control]-y": yank
"[alt].": yank-last-arg
"[alt]_": yank-last-arg
"[alt][control]-y": yank-nth-arg
"[alt]y": yank-pop
```

the remanding 36 I have not deciphered yet;

```
bind -p 2>/dev/null \
| grep -vP "digit-argument|do-lowercase-version|not bound|self-insert" \
| perl -pe 's/\\e/[alt]/g;s/\\C/[control]/g' \
| grep -vP "[\-\]].\""

"[alt]OD": backward-char
"[alt][D": backward-char
"[alt][alt][D": backward-word
"[alt][1;5D": backward-word
"[alt][5D": backward-word
"[alt]OH": beginning-of-line
"[alt][1~": beginning-of-line
"[alt][H": beginning-of-line
"[alt][200~": bracketed-paste-begin
"[control]-xe": call-last-kbd-macro
"[alt][alt]": complete
"[alt][3~": delete-char
"[alt]\\": delete-horizontal-space
"[control]-x)": end-kbd-macro
"[alt]OF": end-of-line
"[alt][4~": end-of-line
"[alt][F": end-of-line
"[alt]OC": forward-char
"[alt][C": forward-char
"[alt][alt][C": forward-word
"[alt][1;5C": forward-word
"[alt][5C": forward-word
"[control]-x*": glob-expand-word
"[control]-xg": glob-list-expansions
"[alt]OB": next-history
"[alt][B": next-history
"[control]-x!": possible-command-completions
"[control]-x/": possible-filename-completions
"[control]-x@": possible-hostname-completions
"[control]-x~": possible-username-completions
"[control]-x$": possible-variable-completions
"[alt]OA": previous-history
"[alt][A": previous-history
"[alt][2~": quoted-insert
"[control]-x(": start-kbd-macro
```

For example I know one of these 3 must be <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>;

```
bind -p | grep forward-word | grep \\[
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
```

but I know not which one, or what the others are.
Is there a list of what these 36 typically map to?

[EDIT1]
Thanks to @undercat for the `^V` tip I was able to get my unknowns down to 7.

```
bind -p 2>/dev/null \
| grep -vP "digit-argument|do-lowercase-version|not bound|self-insert" \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[A/[up]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[B/[down]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[C/[right]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[D/[left]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[1;5A/[control]-[up]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[1;5B/[control]-[down]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[1;5C/[control]-[right]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[1;5D/[control]-[left]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[2~/[control]-[insert]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e\[3~/[control]-[delete]/g' \
| perl -pe 's/\\e/[alt]/g;s/\\C/[control]/g' \
| grep -P "\[[^\]]*\"" \
| perl -pe 's/\[alt\]/\\e/g;s/\[control\]/\\C/g'

"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[200~": bracketed-paste-begin
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
"\e[5C": forward-word
```

[EDIT2]
Thanks to @JdeBP for the nosh and `printf` tips, but the output of decode-ecma48 (from nosh-terminal-management_1.39_amd64) is equally indecipherable to me;

```
... \
| perl -pe 's/:.*//g;s/"//g;s/^/\\/g' \
| xargs -I {} printf '{}' \
| ./console-decode-ecma48

CUB 5
DEC FIND
CUP 0
DEC FNK 200;1
DEC SELECT
CPL 1
CUF 5
```

Can JdeBP or someone translate those vintage abbreviations to full length modern ([example 1](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/Q0/MQ052/MQ052?wid=4000&hei=1800&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_usm=0.5,0.5&.v=1495129815011), [example 2](https://acco-product-images.s3.amazonaws.com/mbank40508_w1400_h1400.jpg), vs an ancient [example](https://lp007819.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/dec-vt320-keyboard-top1.jpg)) keys (if they even map to a modern keyboard)?

Comment: The [manual (Bindable Readline Commands)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html) lists all commands with key sequence and short description.

Comment: @Freddy my question is about mapping in the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the information on key sequences can be gleaned from the `console_codes` man page.
For instance, for `\e[1;5C` we have:

> **ECMA-48 CSI sequences**
>
> CSI (or ESC [) is followed by a sequence of parameters, at most NPAR (16), that are decimal numbers separated by semicolons. (...) The action of a CSI sequence is determined by its final character.

This tells us the first number `1` is the parameter and `C` is the action. Looking further down we can successfully locate the action:

> C   CUF       Move cursor right the indicated # of columns.

Which means the sequence describes the key that moves the cursor right by one symbol... which is the <kbd>→</kbd> key!

The undocumented(?) here prefix `5` indicates the control key. It is mentioned in [the following document](https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html), though I think it would've been easier (but certainly not easy!) to guess it.

I'm unaware of a simple way of converting an escape code like that into a human-readable form, however the conversion in the opposite direction is simple, you just have to press <kbd>C-v</kbd> in Bash followed by a key combination, and its control sequence will show up on the screen in its symbolic form, so for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> will produce `^[[1;5C`.

Comment: A simple way of converting to human readable form, which even knows about various different systems for function keys, is my `console-decode-ecma48`, which you can see in action in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486046/5132 for example. `C` is not a "command".  It is a _final character_.  See https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9268/1932 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439236/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289871/5132 , and all of the doco in their further reading.

Comment: @JdeBP You should consider writing an answer with a brief explanation how to build and use your tool on Linux, it seems very promising and exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @undercat gave you an up vote because that's helpful, but I'm still looking for an applicable solution.

Answer (score 1):

> console-decode-ecma48 did not appear to work;

From the output given in the question, it quite clearly *did* work.  What didn't work was your `echo` command, which you invoked wrongly, not generating control sequences in the first place.  The decoded output shown is what your `echo` command *actually emits*.

```
% echo -n '\e[1;5D'
\e[1;5D%
```

`console-decode-ecma48` decodes the *actual* ECMA-48 control sequences, as used in terminal input and output, not encoded representations of them.  So you need to give to it the actual ECMA-48 control sequences.

There are ways to get `echo` to do this but what happens with `echo` varies from shell to shell and the superior approach is to use `printf`.

```
% printf '\e[1;5D' | console-decode-ecma48 --input
Control+CUB 1
%
```

However, this is not ideal, because the encoding used by GNU Readline is idiosyncratic and not wholly shared with anything else, such as the escape sequences used in `printf` and (sometimes) in `echo`, or in the `vis`/`unvis` encoding.

`printf` will handle many of your remaining unknowns, but cannot translate `\C-` sequences into control codes.  You will need to translate `\C-c` forms beforehand into the octal escape sequences that `printf` understands.  Otherwise it simply will not print the right ECMA-48 character sequence to be decoded in the first place.

```
% printf '\C-g' | console-decode-ecma48 --input
'\'
'C'
'-'
'g'
% printf '\007' | console-decode-ecma48 --input
BEL
%
```

The `--input` option is necessary because this is terminal *input* that you are decoding.  To handle <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key chords you will *also* need the `--no-7bit` option to prevent the decoding of (almost all) ECMA-48 *7-bit code* extensions and other escape sequences, which will otherwise be decoded according to ECMA-48 into their proper meanings.

```
% printf '\eD' | console-decode-ecma48 --input
IND
% printf '\eb' | console-decode-ecma48 --input
EMI
% printf '\eD' | console-decode-ecma48 --input --no-7bit
Meta 'D' 
% printf '\eb' | console-decode-ecma48 --input --no-7bit
Meta 'b' 
%
```

Looping over the output of `bind -p` and feeding the first field sequence by sequence into `printf` (translating `\C-c` into an octal escape beforehand) I leave as an exercise to the reader, as clearly from the question you know how to do that.

For the meanings of the standard abbreviations used in the output, see the explanations and the standards referenced in the manual.

## Further reading

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  "[`console-decode-ecma48`](https://jdebp.uk/Softwares/nosh/guide/console-decode-ecma48.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: Thanks for the printf tip (I up voted you for that) Please address edit 2 of the question before I mark it as solved.

Comment: You didn't use `--input` as I said to use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, using --input produces the same result other than "CUP 0" changes to "CUP 1".