# Why the codes generated by [UP] key changed after ssh session

Tags: ssh, terminal, keyboard, cygwin

I'm in a mintty window of a cygwin environment.

When I typed <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>↑</kbd> key I got : `^[[A`

Then I ssh into Raspberry Pi, and exit immediately.

Now I type <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>↑</kbd> key I get : `^[OA`

```
~$ ^[[A
~$ ssh rasp
Last login: Tue Dec 24 12:08:16 2019 from 192.168.0.5
raspberrypi%
Connection to 192.168.0.12 closed.
~$ ^[OA
```

Can someone help me to understand ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On login, something in the remote shell is initializing your terminal (possibly even the ssh command itself, though that would be a misfeature).  The `^[[A` is a normal-mode and `^[OA` an application-mode (see [summary](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys) in *XTerm Control Sequences*), and applications such as `screen` which initialize the terminal for full-screen operations typically use the terminal initialization capabilities in the terminal description.  mintty has its own terminal description, but sets `TERM` to `xterm`.  So you're getting xterm's initialization string (see [xterm-basic](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html#tic-xterm-basic)), probably `smkx`:

> `smkx=\E[?1h\E=`

which is two settings:

- **`\E[?1h`** [*Ps = 1  ⇒  Application Cursor Keys (DECCKM), VT100.*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-1.1E61)
- **`\E=`** [*ESC =     Application Keypad (DECKPAM).*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Controls-beginning-with-ESC:ESC-=.C6B)

If this is just a case of an application setting something and not resetting it (using the same terminal description), you could follow up by

```
tput rmkx
```

(removing that mode).  Doing that inside of screen or tmux would confuse the screen/tmux program; doing it inside of some other program also might not be good...

Comment: Great explanation ! even though I don't fully understand :-) One more question, is there a way to get ^[[A back after ssh ?

Comment: For background, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444270/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465308/5132 , and their further reading.

Comment: @JdeBP, 
How did you convert my text "Ctrl" into a symbol ?

Comment: If you edit your answer, you'll see something like `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>` which becomes Ctrl  specially marked when saved (doesn 't work in comments though).